# How to maximize the width of ggplot bar chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

Assume i have used the ggplot which works quit well. The code is below:

```
female<-subset(fl_Estonia,Sex=="F"  )
roles<-ggplot(female,aes(Role,fill=Role))+
  geom_bar(col=rainbow(length(table(female$Role))))
roles+theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,hjust=1),legend.position="none")
```

The output is such below picture:

[image]
The point is, the plot is a bit condense, so **i would like to use the empty space on the right handside of the image?**

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem, when `legend.position = "none"` is set then there is no legend and the plot fills the space.

Comment: IN what environment are you working? Is this an R Notebook, some kind of R Markdown? Are you showing in screen? Generating a file?

Answer (score 0):

You can for example increase the width (`width = ...`) **and/or** space between the bars (`position_dodge(width = ...)`) in `geom_bar()`:

```
...+ geom_bar(width = 1, position = position_dodge(width = 1)) +
```

In your case exactly:

```
female<-subset(fl_Estonia,Sex=="F"  )
roles<-ggplot(female,aes(Role,fill=Role))+
  geom_bar(width = 1, position = position_dodge(width = 1),col=rainbow(length(table(female$Role))))
roles+theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,hjust=1),legend.position="none")
```

**[!]** This solution will not work properly in `RMarkdown` or `Shiny`! As you have not specified exactly in which environment it is, i assumed that you just wanna get the plot.